# How to apply CIPhotoEffectMono filter on image in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, core-image

This is my code for filter:

```
let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIPhotoEffectMono")
filter!.setValue(CIImage(image: imageView.image!) , forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
filter!.setValue(0.3, forKey: kCIInputIntensityKey)
let context = CIContext(options:nil)
let cgimg = context.createCGImage(filter!.outputImage!, fromRect: filter!.outputImage!.extent)
let newImage = UIImage(CGImage:cgimg)
self.imageView.image = newImage
```

Here is the error message:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key inputIntensity.'
>
> First throw call stack:
>   (
>
> 0   CoreFoundation    0x0000000105f9af65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
>
> 1   libobjc.A.dylib   0x0000000107f56deb objc_exception_throw + 48
>
> 2   CoreFoundation    0x0000000105f9aba9 -[NSException raise] + 9
>
> 3   CoreImage         0x0000000106354f7a -[CIFilter setValue:forUndefinedKey:] + 137
>
> 4   Foundation        0x000000010668af5b -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 288
>
> 5   MyFirstApp        0x0000000105a26bac _TFC10MyFirstApp14ViewController13lightBlendBtnfS0_FPSs9AnyObject_T_ + 988
>
> 6   MyFirstApp        0x0000000105a27076 _TToFC10MyFirstApp14ViewController13lightBlendBtnfS0_FPSs9AnyObject_T_ + 54
>
> 7   UIKit             0x0000000106ae01fa -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
>
> 8   UIKit             0x0000000106c44504 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
>
> 9   UIKit             0x0000000106c447d0 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 311
>
> 10  UIKit             0x0000000106c43906 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 601
>
> 11  UIKit             0x0000000106b4aaa3 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 835
>
> 12  UIKit             0x0000000106b4b691 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 865
>
> 13  UIKit             0x0000000106afd752 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 263
>
> 14  UIKit             0x00000001140f4a55 -[UIApplicationAccessibility sendEvent:] + 77
>
> 15  UIKit             0x0000000106ad8fcc _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6693
>
> 16  CoreFoundation    0x0000000105ec70a1 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
>
> 17  CoreFoundation    0x0000000105ebcfcc __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
>
> 18  CoreFoundation    0x0000000105ebc483 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
>
> 19  CoreFoundation    0x0000000105ebbe98 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
>
> 20  GraphicsServices  0x000000010cdccad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
>
> 21  UIKit             0x0000000106ade676 UIApplicationMain + 171
>
> 22  MyFirstApp        0x0000000105a29fed main + 109
>
> 23  libdyld.dylib      0x0000000108a8292d start + 1
>
> )
>
> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>   (lldb)

Answer (score 2):

`CIPhotoEffectMono` doesn't support `kCIInputIntensityKey`. In fact none of the photo effect filters have any inputs apart from input image. If you remove `filter!.setValue(0.3, forKey: kCIInputIntensityKey)` your code should work fine.

You can check the supported inputs of a filter with `filter.inputKeys` which returns an array of strings containing the names of all the inputs.

Simon