# Applying a CIFilter with SKEffectNode to a SKSpriteNode

Tags: sprite-kit, swift3, xcode8, cifilter, skeffectnode

I am trying to apply a CIFilter with SKEffectNode to a SKSpriteNode.
Can't get this to work and not sure why. I got this working using a blur but cannot get the mono photo effect.
Anyone have any insight? Thanks again.

```
//Mono Effect (not working)
    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIPhotoEffectMono")
    filter?.setDefaults()
    effectsNode.filter = filter
    self.addChild(effectsNode)
    effectsNode.addChild(SKSpriteNode)

//Blur Effect (working)
    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")
    let blurAmount = 4.0
    filter?.setValue(blurAmount, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)
    effectsNode.filter = filter
    effectsNode.blendMode = .alpha
    self.addChild(effectsNode)
    effectNode.addChild(SKSpriteNode)
```

Comment: I just tested your code and both filters worked as expected.

Comment: does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38395197/how-to-apply-ciphotoeffectmono-filter-on-image-in-ios

Comment: are you setting `shouldEnableEffects` to `true`?  Also, provide an example that actually works,  your code as of right now will not compile

Comment: Okay so the first effect is working now. I don't know why it wasn't working for me before. And both effects compiled fine for me. So I guess my next question is do you know how to make an effect like this fade in. So it looks like an SKSpriteNode gradually fades to mono? Thanks!

Comment: blend alphas between two image states (two different sprites, same content, different states), one that's coloured, one that's mono.

Comment: Theres a lot of moving sprites in the app, creating double the sprites to achieve this effect would be inefficient. Especially because I am using an emitter node that randomly emits nodes across the screen.